# How to call controller from javascript CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I need to call a controller from javascript. I've already success to call the controller, but if the controller has no paramater.
In my cases, the controller has a parameter. How can i can call the controller from javascript

Javascript code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
var thisTable = setFilterGrid("myTable");

document.getElementById("oneday").onclick = function() {
    var date = new Date();

    var day = date.getDate().toString();
    var month = date.getMonth().toString();
    var year = date.getFullYear().toString();

    var oneday = day.concat('/', month, '/', year);

    window.location.href = "<?php echo site_url('sellbyitem/retrieveInfo('/*howcanipassonedayhere*/');?>";
};
```

Controller:

```
public function retrieveInfo($date) {
    echo $date;
}
```

I've already looking for same cases, but it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass javascript parameter at end like following :

```
window.location.href = "<?php echo site_url('sellbyitem/retrieveInfo/');?>" + oneday ;
```